# Cartesian product of list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to produce a permutation of multiple strings based on a given integer in the first line. For example,

```
Input: 
3
abc
de
fgh

Output:
adf 
adg 
adh 
aef 
aeg 
aeh 
bdf 
bdg 
bdh....
```

I have this in mind:

```
str1 = "abc"
str2 = "de"
str3 = "fgh"
for char in str1:
    for i in str2:
        for j in str3:
                print(char + i + j )
```

this would print the said output... and as the number of strings becomes 4:

```
str1 = "pfpdh"
str2 = "jp"
str3 = "fo"
str4 = "aeuqj"
for char in str1:
    for i in str2:
        for j in str3:
            for k in str4:
                print(char + i + j + k)
```

I was instructed to construct the recursive version... I hope you could help me...

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter i have this in mind... how could i represent this in a recursive version?

Comment: ```str1 = "abc",
str2 = "de",
str3 = "fgh",
for char in str1:
    for i in str2:
        for j in str3:
            print(char + i + j)```

Comment: nvm the comments, i'll just update the question to be understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to developing a recursive solution is to assume you already have one that works for smaller versions of the problem.  (The idea is that if it can handle the smallest case (the *base case*) directly, and any recursive call is on a smaller problem, you always eventually get to that base case.)

To wit:

```
def cart_prod( list_of_strings ):
    if len(list_of_strings) == 1:
        return [c for c in list_of_strings[0]]
    else:
        tails = cart_prod( list_of_strings[1:] )
        # combine each letter from list_of_strings[0] to each element of tails
```

I'll leave completion as an exercise.